# How to prevent all lines from being deleted in PineScript

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm editing an indicator that keeps deleting all lines above line.all. Unfortunately, lines from other indicators in the same script are also deleted. I would use indicators in a script but ensure that the lines are only deleted in the routine of the affected indicator. Is there a solution to this.

Here is the affected area in the script:

```
if not show1 and not show2
        valC1 := float(na)
        valC2 := float(na)
    else
        a_allLines = line.all      // garbage collection
        if array.size(a_allLines) > 0
            for i = 0 to array.size(a_allLines) - 1
                line.delete(array.get(a_allLines, i))
```

Here is the entire indicator used:

```
evnHi = timestamp("10 Nov 2021 00:00 +0000") // default event for AVWAP hi
evnLo = timestamp("21 Sep 2021 00:00 +0000") // default event for AVWAP lo
evnHO = timestamp("24 Jan 2022 00:00 +0000") // default event for AVWAP handoff

colHi = #ff00664d  // default color for AVWAP event hi
colLo = #ff00ff4d  // default color for AVWAP event lo
colHO = #9900ff4d  // default color for AVWAP handoff
col1D = #0000ffb3  // default color for AVWAP daily
col2D = #00ffffb3  // default color for AVWAP previous daily
col1W = #00ff00b3  // default color for AVWAP weekly
col1M = #ffff00b3  // default color for AVWAP monthly
col3M = #ff6600b3  // default color for AVWAP quarterly
col1Y = #ff0000b3  // default color for AVWAP yearly
colrd = #1E56DAff  // default color for AVWAP dividends
colre = #04806Bff  // default color for AVWAP earnings #cc2f3cff
colrs = #fb8c00ff  // default color for AVWAP splits
colah = #f23645ff  // default color for AVWAP auto1
colal = #089981ff  // default color for AVWAP auto2

toolD = "[Event Date] [Event Time]\nSet the desired Date & Time or drag the vertical anchor line to a significant Event on chart."
toolE = "[Source] [Zone Type] [Zone Width] [Color]\nSet the anchored VWAP's desired Source, Zone Type, Zone Width, and Color."
toolI = "[Source] [Interval] [Line Width] [Color]\nSet the periodic VWAP's desired Source, Interval, Line Width, and Color."
toolA = "[Signal] [Source] [Line Width] [Color]\nSet the automatic VWAP's desired Signal, Source, Line Width, and Color."
toolS = "[Length] [Bars Left] [Bars Right]\nSet the desired Length applicable for Highest, Lowest, Highest Volume " +
 ", and Lowest Volume. Set the desired number of Bars Left & Bars Right applicable for Pivot Hi or Pivot Lo."

// inputs auto
shoAH = input.bool     (true,       'Show',                                                 inline = 'H', group = 'Auto')
typAH = input.string   ('Highest',   '',                                   tooltip = toolA,  inline = 'H', group = 'Auto',
 options = ['Highest', 'Lowest', 'Highest Volume', 'Lowest Volume', 'Pivot High', 'Pivot Low'])
srcAH = input.source   (open,        '',                                                     inline = 'H', group = 'Auto')
widAH = input.int      (5,           '',           minval = 1,                               inline = 'H', group = 'Auto')
colAH = input.color    (colah,       '',                                                     inline = 'H', group = 'Auto')
lenAH = input.int      (7,          'SignalBars', minval = 1,                               inline = 'h', group = 'Auto')
plbAH = input.int      (2,           '',           minval = 0,                               inline = 'h', group = 'Auto')
prbAH = input.int      (0,           '',           minval = 0,             tooltip = toolS,  inline = 'h', group = 'Auto')

shoAL = input.bool     (true,       'Show',                                                 inline = 'L', group = 'Auto')
typAL = input.string   ('Lowest',    '',                                   tooltip = toolA,  inline = 'L', group = 'Auto',
 options = ['Highest', 'Lowest', 'Highest Volume', 'Lowest Volume', 'Pivot High', 'Pivot Low'])
srcAL = input.source   (close,         '',                                                     inline = 'L', group = 'Auto')
widAL = input.int      (5,           '',           minval = 1,                               inline = 'L', group = 'Auto')
colAL = input.color    (colal,       '',                                                     inline = 'L', group = 'Auto')
lenAL = input.int      (7,          'SignalBars', minval = 1,                               inline = 'l', group = 'Auto')
plbAL = input.int      (2,           '',           minval = 0,                               inline = 'l', group = 'Auto')
prbAL = input.int      (0,           '',           minval = 0,             tooltip = toolS,  inline = 'l', group = 'Auto')

// returns auto vwaps from signals within lengths of bars or pivots
svwap(
 show1, source1, signal1, length1, barsL1, barsR1, color1, width1,
 show2, source2, signal2, length2, barsL2, barsR2, color2, width2) =>
    idxCB = bar_index              // index current bar

    valS1 = float(na)              // value signal source1
    idxS1 = int(na)                // index signal source1
    sS1V1 = float(na)              // sum of source1 * volume1
    sVol1 = float(na)              // sum of volume1
    valP1 = float(na)              // previous value of svwap1
    valC1 = float(na)              // current value of svwap1

    valS2 = float(na)              // value signal source2
    idxS2 = int(na)                // index signal source2
    sS2V2 = float(na)              // sum of source2 * volume2
    sVol2 = float(na)              // sum of volume2
    valP2 = float(na)              // previous value of svwap2
    valC2 = float(na)              // current value of svwap2
    lines = line(na)               // lines drawn for each bar of avwap   
     
    if not show1 and not show2
        valC1 := float(na)
        valC2 := float(na)
    else
        a_allLines = line.all      // garbage collectionnes
        if array.size(a_allLines) > 0
            for i = 0 to array.size(a_allLines) - 1
                line.delete(array.get(a_allLines, i))  

        if show1                   // calc auto vwap1
            valS1 :=
             signal1 == 'Highest' ? ta.highest(source1, length1) :
             signal1 == 'Lowest'  ? ta.lowest (source1, length1) :
             signal1 == 'Highest Volume' ? ta.highest(volume, length1) :
             signal1 == 'Lowest Volume'  ? ta.lowest (volume, length1) :
             signal1 == 'Pivot High' ?
              ta.valuewhen(not na(ta.pivothigh(source1, barsL1, barsR1)), source1[barsR1], 0) :
             signal1 == 'Pivot Low'  ?
              ta.valuewhen(not na(ta.pivotlow (source1, barsL1, barsR1)), source1[barsR1], 0) :              
             float(na)
            if signal1 == 'Highest' or signal1 == 'Lowest'
                for i = 0 to length1 - 1
                    if source1[i] == valS1 
                        idxS1 := bar_index[i]
                        break
            if signal1 == 'Highest Volume' or signal1 == 'Lowest Volume'
                for i = 0 to length1 - 1
                    if volume[i] == valS1 
                        idxS1 := bar_index[i]
                        break
            if signal1 == 'Pivot High' or signal1 == 'Pivot Low'
                idxS1 :=
                 signal1 == 'Pivot High' ?
                  ta.valuewhen(not na(ta.pivothigh(source1, barsL1, barsR1)), bar_index[barsR1], 0) :
                 signal1 == 'Pivot Low'  ?
                  ta.valuewhen(not na(ta.pivotlow (source1, barsL1, barsR1)), bar_index[barsR1], 0) :
                 int(na)   

            nBars = 1 + idxCB - idxS1    
            for i = nBars - 1 to 0 // draw lines for current event vwap
                sS1V1 := nz(sS1V1) + nz(source1[i] * volume[i])
                sVol1 := nz(sVol1) + nz(volume[i])
                valP1 := nz(valC1, na)
                valC1 := sS1V1 / sVol1
                lines := line.new(idxCB - i - 1, valP1, idxCB - i, valC1, xloc.bar_index, extend.none, color1, width = width1)

        if show2                   // calc auto vwap2
            valS2 :=
             signal2 == 'Highest' ? ta.highest(source2, length2) :
             signal2 == 'Lowest'  ? ta.lowest (source2, length2) :
             signal2 == 'Highest Volume' ? ta.highest(volume, length2) :
             signal2 == 'Lowest Volume'  ? ta.lowest (volume, length2) :             
             signal2 == 'Pivot High' ?
              ta.valuewhen(not na(ta.pivothigh(source2, barsL2, barsR2)), source1[barsR2], 0) :
             signal2 == 'Pivot Low'  ?
              ta.valuewhen(not na(ta.pivotlow (source2, barsL2, barsR2)), source1[barsR2], 0) :   
             float(na)
            if signal2 == 'Highest' or signal2 == 'Lowest'
                for i = 0 to length2 - 1
                    if source2[i] == valS2 
                        idxS2 := bar_index[i]
                        break
            if signal2 == 'Highest Volume' or signal2 == 'Lowest Volume'
                for i = 0 to length2 - 1
                    if volume[i] == valS2 
                        idxS2 := bar_index[i]
                        break
            if signal2 == 'Pivot High' or signal2 == 'Pivot Low'
                idxS2 :=
                 signal2 == 'Pivot High' ?
                  ta.valuewhen(not na(ta.pivothigh(source2, barsL2, barsR2)), bar_index[barsR2], 0) :
                 signal2 == 'Pivot Low'  ?
                  ta.valuewhen(not na(ta.pivotlow (source2, barsL2, barsR2)), bar_index[barsR2], 0) :
                 int(na)   

            nBars = 1 + idxCB - idxS2     
            for i = nBars - 1 to 0 // draw lines for current event vwap
                sS2V2 := nz(sS2V2) + nz(source2[i] * volume[i])
                sVol2 := nz(sVol2) + nz(volume[i])
                valP2 := nz(valC2, na)
                valC2 := sS2V2 / sVol2
                lines := line.new(idxCB - i - 1, valP2, idxCB - i, valC2, xloc.bar_index, extend.none, color2, width = width2)
        
    [valC1, valC2]

[vwap1, vwap2] = svwap(
 shoAH, srcAH, typAH, lenAH, plbAH, prbAH, colAH, widAH,
 shoAL, srcAL, typAL, lenAL, plbAL, prbAL, colAL, widAL)
```

Comment: Please only tag the version of pine-script your code is written in. I don't see any version declaration in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Put the lines in a `var` array so that you can track. Then pass this array to your function and delete the lines in the array.

Comment: Is there an example? I'm not very familiar with arrays